# Как разделить строку в sql на разные столбцы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в sql можно распарсить строку по конкретному разделителю и записать полученные части в разные столбцы.

У меня есть строка: `'16001=4,16002=4,16003=4,16005=1,16007=3'`.
Нужно реализовать что-то в роде таблицы `(номер, значение: 16001, 4)`.

Я понял что через `STRING_SPLIT` можно разделить на строки по символу `,`.
В итоге полученный результат можно прогнать через цикл, где строку `16001=4` разделить на `16001` и `4`. В этом у меня проблема. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.

Использую SQL Server Management Studio 18.7.

Сейчас я имею функцию, на которую подаю строку и получаю табличное значение:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertStringToTable](@inputString NVARCHAR(400))
RETURNS @tabl TABLE(value NVARCHAR(100)) AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT @tabl
            SELECT value  
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@inputString, ',')  
                WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
        RETURN 
    END
```

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? В разных СУБД есть разные возможности.

Comment: СУБД в общем случае недостаточно, нужна to и точная версия.\

Comment: Использую SQL Server Management Studio 18.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select left(value,charindex('=',value)-1),
SUBSTRING(value,charindex('=',value)+1,len(@inputString))  
from string_split(@inputString,',')
```

Comment: Похоже это оно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Версия SSMS не имеет значения.

Чтобы получить версию SQL Server, введите следующую команду:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Вот несколько более эффективный метод, потому что он вычисляет позицию знака равенства только один раз для пары ключ/значение.

```
DECLARE @inputString VARCHAR(MAX) = '16001=4,16002=4,16003=4,16005=1,1600770=3';

SELECT LEFT(value, t.pos - 1) AS [key],
    RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - t.pos) AS [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@inputString, ',')
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT pos = CHARINDEX('=',value)) AS t;
```

**Результат**

```
+---------+-------+
|   key   | value |
+---------+-------+
|   16001 |     4 |
|   16002 |     4 |
|   16003 |     4 |
|   16005 |     1 |
| 1600770 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```